# Azure B2C graph api rejects delete user with insufficient privileges

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

As shown below we have assign most of the permissions required to call the B2C graph api. We call this through backend rest api. We can create, update and get users without any issues. But Delete returns with

```html
"odata.error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en",
      "value": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
    },
    "requestId": "10ab3bff-8594-4d27-b6b4-f0ca186b5b6f74",
    "date": "2021-03-09T02:33:01"
  }
```

What other permissions required? Code is based on https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-GraphAPI-DotNet.

[image]

Comment: The account which you are using to call the delete user API is a global administrator?

Comment: Dont know about the account. We use model from
https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-GraphAPI-DotNet
Which users ClientCredential


this.credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample you are using actually calls AAD Graph API rather than Microsoft Graph API.

AAD Graph is on a deprecation path. Starting June 30th, 2020 we will no longer add any new features to Azure AD Graph API.

Providing `Directory.ReadWrite.All` won't allow you to delete the users through AAD Graph currently.

You need to assign a "User administrator" to the service principal associated with your app registration. Then you are able to delete the user.

Here are the steps:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]